# Triggering based in modified file pattern with per-commit evaluation (instead of per-PR evaluation)

Tags: github, github-actions

Let's consider a GitHub Actions workflow like this one:

```
name: Check in JSON files
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - '**/*.json'
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
    paths:
      - '**/*.json'      
jobs:
  model_validation:
    ...
```

The idea is to check only in the case JSON files are modified. So, I can have a sequence of commits in my PR like this:

| commit | modification | workflow triggered? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | .md file modified | no |
| 2 | .py file modified | no |
| 3 | .json file modified | yes |

So far so good.

The problem is that if new commits are added, the workflow is triggered, no matter the kind of file the commit modifies. Let's consider in the above example PR that I add two new commits modifying not .json files. What I get is:

| commit | modification | workflow triggered? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | .md file modified | no |
| 2 | .py file modified | no |
| 3 | .json file modified | yes |
| 4 | .py file modified | yes |
| 5 | .md file modified | yes |

while I would like to get this:

| commit | modification | workflow triggered? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | .md file modified | no |
| 2 | .py file modified | no |
| 3 | .json file modified | yes |
| 4 | .py file modified | no |
| 5 | .md file modified | no |

My understanding is that the `paths` condition is evaluated at *PR level* (i.e. summing all the commits in the PR). So, given the sum from 1 to 6 includes a .json file, the workflow is triggered. What I'm looking for is for *commit level* evaluation.

Thus, is there any way of achieving what I want (i.e. per commit file path evaluation)? In that case, how would it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution (although I'm not sure is the optimal one) removing the `pull_request` section, this way:

```
name: Check in JSON files
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - '**/*.json'      
jobs:
  model_validation:
    ...
```

Doing so, I achieve the desired case:

| commit | modification | workflow triggered? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | .md file modified | no |
| 2 | .py file modified | no |
| 3 | .json file modified | yes |
| 4 | .py file modified | no |
| 5 | .md file modified | no |